# change color and underline in button(active)

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

The effect that I wanted is an active underline and change color. When I click on a button, the button will change color and have a underline.

```css
.menu_item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu_link {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: grey;
  letter-spacing: 0.6px;
}

.menu_link:hover,
.menu_link.active {
  color: black;
}

.menu_link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 125%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: -.8rem;
  background-color: black;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.menu_link:hover:after,
.menu_link.active:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu p-0">
  <li class="menu_item me-5">
    <a class="text-decoration-none menu_link" type="button" id="btnContact">Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu_item">
    <a class="text-decoration-none menu_link" type="button" id="btnLocation">Location</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The Buttons
[image]

And I have tried with JS but I don't know how to add :after(underline effect) in onclick JS.

```js
var btnMenu1 = document.getElementById("btnContact");
var btnMenu2 = document.getElementById("btnLocation");

btnMenu1.onclick = function() {
  btnMenu1.style.color = "black";
  btnMenu2.style.color = "grey";
}
btnMenu2.onclick = function() {
  btnMenu1.style.color = "grey";
  btnMenu2.style.color = "black";
}
```

//Any help or tutorials are appreciated, thank you!//

================================================================
closed, the solution:

```js
var menuActive = '.menu_link';
        $(menuActive).on('click', function(){
            $(menuActive).removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
```

Comment: @isherwood you can see the screenshot above, on the button "contact us" it hover. the problem is how to make the effect when the button is active.

Comment: Seems like you may want the [:active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) pseudo-class   Your code uses .active (dot class name) which doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @Yogi I've tried it too, change .active (class name) to .menu_link.:active / .menu_link:active:after (pseudo-class), and it's doesn't work at all.

Comment: I was able to make it work using the :active pseudo-class.  Part of the problem is your html.  The links are set to type=button, but that's invalid.  Remove these because type intended for a different purpose (file download links).  And the links need an href attribute for :active to work. So add href="#" as a placeholder. You should be able to make some progress after these fixes.